# Symfony 5 - In Controller, execute migration

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine, migration

I'm looking for a way to execut the command which make migration into a controller.
I already took a look at doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html but it doesn't really give a response to my question.

What i want : Be able to execute php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate in a controller.
Moreover, there no security problem by doing this ?

Have a nice day !

Comment: please have a look at this https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to change database schema runtime. You may encounter unforeseen effects in your application w.r.t test cases, performance in broader term, etc.